# Avoid call to a nested resolver if all the response fields have been already fulfilled

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a schema that receive a `timeInterval` iput on root query and the pass it to nested levels/resolvers. I'm trying to add validation to that input on `root` level, so if the validation fails then I should return and `error` and return `null` for other fields. The issue is that if I do this on `root` level then I don't know how to avoid `graphql-tools` calling nested resolvers (which fails because they don't have the `timeInterval` variable defined in the `obj` of each resolver).

Let me know know if you need and schema example and more details, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is built in to how GraphQL.js, the reference implementation from Facebook, works. GraphQL-Tools is just a library on top that makes writing resolvers and schemas a bit nicer.

In GraphQL.js, the child resolvers are called whenever the parent resolver returns anything other than `null` or `undefined`, or if it throws an error.

So it sounds like in your case you are returning some data but with a single field missing, in which case GraphQL.js has no idea that it should avoid calling nested fields. Having more detail about your schema and resolvers would definitely help me come up with a specific solution.